# How to pass form-data while calling API using Jmeter?

Tags: api, jmeter

I want to make an API call using Jmeter.

In my API call, I'm sending a file with a request,
and I need to specify the file name as form-data.

e.g. when I call the same API from postman ![image]

How do I, specify a filename when I make above call from Jmeter?

Jmeter call :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) provides options to

- set `Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST`
- send files with the request

[image: Multipart upload]

See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed explanations and configuration instructions.

Comment: I've done exactly same . But my question is how to pass form-data which you can see in first screen shot (postman call). I've also edited question with Jmeter screen shot. Please take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: just add another parameter under "parentfolderid" with the name of "filename" and value of "new-batch". Actually you can record file upload with JMeter, just put the file into /bin folder of your JMeter installation and it should capture everything you need

Comment: still something missing..!!
It doesn't get even first parameter
 
POST data:
`--6Otiwu8KvIwa06ShtpSK8_X4W3oXSQC_6lgiwk0`
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parentfolderid"`
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII`
`Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

`65128`
`--6Otiwu8KvIwa06ShtpSK8_X4W3oXSQC_6lgiwk0`
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"`
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII`
`Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

`new-batch`
`--6Otiwu8KvIwa06ShtpSK8_X4W3oXSQC_6lgiwk0--`


Response:
`<error><ref>403</ref><summary>Missing  parentfolderid ``parameter</summary></error>`

Comment: It looks like you haven't provided value for "parentfolderid" or the value is incorrect

Comment: **65128** is value of "parentfolderid" and it also shows me in Post data.
With same value I can make call from postman and it will work fine.

Comment: In that case try adding it into URL path like you do in postman

Comment: It gives `<status>400</status>` `<message>Request resource or xml is not valid</message>`

Comment: It gives 400 because fail to find expected form-data parameter.
I'm getting same response from postman if i remove form-data.
So, problem is only how to pass expected @FormDataParam .?

Comment: An FYI, ran into the same issue and was able to solve it.

I was following this tutorial https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/performance-testing-of-a-restful-api-using-jmeter ;the problem was that the tutorial tells to use HTTP header manager to set “Content-Type” to “application/json”, while here we are using "content-type":"multipart/form-data" (was able to discover the difference by comparing output from Postman console and request headers via results tree in Jmeter). On removing the default header got correct header ("multipart/form-data") in output and it worked.