# How to pass form-data values In Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

Screenshot 1:
From postman, I'm passing **form-data** under body and the request is working fine.

[image]

And I would like to pass same format from Jmeter, but unable to do it, here is my Jmeter attachment.
[image]

But the issue is, from Jmeter we're passing them under Parameters tab, since we're not passing as Form-data, request is failing. Can anyone help me **"How to pass form-data under body"** for the request?

**

- Note:

** I have tried passing form-data under params, headers still it's not working, **getting 500 Error**

Excellent if someone can help me out on this.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: Similar question I found: but there is no resolution: 
Link is below for question 

FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390380/how-to-pass-form-data-while-calling-api-using-jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this "files" parameter should go under "Files Upload" tab otherwise JMeter will just send `img.jpg` as the plain text.

[image]

In general given you're able to send the request in Postman successfully you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
3. In case of HTTPS traffic [import JMeter's self-signed certificate to Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)
4. Copy the file you're going to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder
5. Execute the request in Postman
6. JMeter should generate propert [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Comment: Hi, I have tried passing file under file upload, but there are some other form-data parameter that I want to send.

If we look at first screenshot there is param "inputJson", this value i need to pass as form-data under body in Jmeter.

Note: I don't have any issue with Postman, it's working fine, only issue is in Jmeter, how to pass form-data as part of request body.

Comment: I'll also try recording from the postman like you explained and I'll update here.

Comment: Thaks @Dmitri it worked for me after recording from postman.! Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

After recording from the Postman, as described in "https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling" in this link, It works fine for me.